# Creating Rest API Laravel (Showing 404)

Tags: laravel

I created a Laravel Api-rest, but when i'm accessing the api endpoint it's responding me 404 not found. I added the endpoint in api.php

The url that I'm accessing is localhost:8000/api/my_first_api
but the browser returns 404 not found.

```
Route::get('my_first_api',
   'HomeController@my_first_api')>name('my_first_api');
```

HomeController.php :

```
public function my_first_api()
{
   $home_content = DB::select('SELECT * FROM content_structure WHERE content_pages = ? ',[
        'Home'
   ]);

    return response()->json(array(['data' => $home_content]));
}
```

RouteServiceProvider.php :

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));


}
```

My Route List:
[image: Router]

Comment: If you are using `laravel-5.5` then you need to use `laravel resource api` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources

Comment: @AyazShah is that recommended to use eloquent rather than query builder?

Comment: You can use both of them but eloquent would be good approach

Comment: ok, but i try first the builder to test if it's working.. do you have idea why is not working for that?

Comment: try `php artisan route:list` command and see if your route is there

Comment: GET|HEAD | api/my_first_api       | my_first_api     | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@my_first_api

Comment: @MianHaseeb yes my route is there

Comment: can you show your api route file?

Comment: that is the only route in my file

Comment: Are you accessing the route in browser?

Comment: @vpalade yes ... i tried to access localhost:8000/api/my_first_api, but when i press enter, it goes to route of login..

Comment: the route of web.php is working , however the api.php is not working.

Comment: seems you have auth middleware somewhere

Comment: yes, i use the php artisan make:auth

Comment: @vpalade, do you mean if i use the auth middleware the api route will be not working??

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: fresh installation to laravel docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185113/discussion-between-vpalade-and-devge).

Answer (score 1):

Please Check Your Code

```
 Route::get('my_first_api',
   'HomeController@my_first_api')->name('my_first_api');
```

And Just add public in url before api.

```
localhost:8000/public/api/my_first_api
```